# Blender Graphics On/Off

Tags: game-engine

we are currently working on making blender for a real time application for use in broadcast. We are using it to play on graphics in American football, layered over top of the field and played back using Blender's decklink capabilities in the BGE. What I would like to know is is it possible to have a graphic fade on screen at a command and fade back off at a command?

Comment: you can animate transparency in the BGE, but not opacity. This means that you can have solid colors fade on/off, but you won't be able to have partially transparent textures fade in/out.

Comment: Let me make sure I get you right: It is only 0% or 100%, nothing in between? Additionally is it possible to do more than fading, like animated transitions?